# YouTube Data Api v3 - subscriptions.list and mine = true

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I found following problem.

If user is authorized with youtube and you call subscriptions.list with parameter mine set to true. Then you get a list of subscriptions of authorized user. This works just fine if user has YouTube account linked with g+ page or if user has its own channel on YouTube. But if it is just a normal user without a channel and g+ page then this request returns "subscriberNotFound" error.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a channel to subscribe, so that's normal.

You can read [this blog for working with channel ids](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids).

Also please use stackoverflow for only programming issues.

As [suggested here, you should file bug reports or features request in public issue tracker](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/09/the-youtube-api-on-stack-overflow.html).

Comment: But I have an account that is subscribed to multiple channels and it has not created its own channel. Also api v2 returns his subscriptions just fine. But v3 returns this error.

Comment: Can you push this issue back to you team: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5261&thanks=5261&ts=1379918045 They missed a very important fact that this works for g+ users without a channel and it works on v2 api.

Comment: Replied to your issue in tracker. use subscriptions->list for everyone, if you get the error, return empty list or ask users to create a channel.

Answer (score -1):

The call to subscriptions.list **can't** return a subscriptionNotFound Error. This is an error which only occurs when you try to delete a subscription. Maybe you are calling the wrong method? Take a look at [this link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#try-it) for more information on the possible error codes, and details why they occur. For all Error codes look [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors)

Comment: how can you say it can't return if it is in docs: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#try-it can return it without a problem...

Comment: It can only return "subscriberNotFound" and "subscriptionForbidden" regarding the subscriptions. Read carefully!

Comment: Ok my bad. Error is "subscriberNotFound".

Comment: Could you provide the username which leads to the problems?

Comment: Any YT user that has not created channel and still hasn't connected with g+ page has this problem.